# How to make a pop-up dialog appear only once in sketchware?

Tags: popupwindow

Im new here. Let me introduce myself. I like learning new things. So I started my programming career by creating simple and useful apps. Today I came into a question on how to create a simple app that shows a pop-up dialog only on the first time launching the app. This dialog has an OK button which if pressed, it gets me to a new Intent (say TwoActivity.class). If I will close this app and relaunch it again, this pop-up will not appear again, until I will erase application data and cache on device settings.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Dialog: firstuse Title: First Launch

Dialog: firstuse Message: This is your first launch. Go to TwoActivity.

| Dialog: firstuse OK Button: Go

| Shared Preferences: firstuse set key: firstuse data: no

| Intent: firstuse setScreen TwoActivity

| startActivity Intent: firstuse
|____________________________/

| Dialog: firstuse Cancel Button: Close App

| finishActivity

|_____________________________/

If not (Shared Preferences: firstuse getKey: "firstuse" equals no)
then Dialog: firstuse show

I hope that works for you. If it is a bit confusing, try to imagine the above as Sketchware Blocks. It is not code.